# NodeJS MongoDB : Multiple save requests not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I am using `node-mongodb-native` in my application. I send multiple `POST` requests to nodejs server to save/update each documents, but only one document is getting updated and all other document are not changing. The data received in the server is correct.

```
save : function(req,res) {
        data = req.body;            
        if(!data._id){  
            data._id = new ObjectID();
        }else{
            data._id = ObjectID(data._id);          
        }       
        mColl(req.params.collname, function (collection,db) {
            collection.save(data, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {                  
                 if(err){
                    res.send(err);
                 }
                 else {
                    res.send(result);
                 }              
            });
        });
    }
```

I am not getting the response  for the request also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, don't do this:

```
data = req.body;
```

When a new request comes in, you're overwriting the (global!) `data` variable, and all kinds of undefined stuff can happen. So always declare a new variable:

```
var data = req.body;
```